# Record relationships within one table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to implement my own [NACE code](http://ec.europa.eu/competition/mergers/cases/index/nace_all.html) database, and have found a **.CSV** file with all the codes and their respective names so that I don't have to enter them all by hand.

Problem is, the codes are all in one **.CSV** file. Is it possible to dump them[NACE codes] all into one table and then somehow distinguish the parent-child relationships between them all?

So, for example if all the codes are imported into table names "**tnacecodes**":

> J62 - Computer programming, consultancy and related activities

will be the parent of

> J62.0.1 - Computer programming activities
>
> J62.0.2 - Computer consultancy activities
>
> J62.0.3 - Computer facilities management activities
>
> J62.0.9 - Other information technology and computer service activities

even though they are all in one table.

What I will do with this is create PHP page with nested links. By clicking on a higher level NACE codes(i.e. J62) the PHP script will retrieve the sub related codes(J62.0.1, J62.0.2,...) and display them on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column with a parent link for each item. This allows a hierarchical structure (conceptually) in a single table. You can access the children of an item by searching for items with parent links to that item.

Comment: Pretty much what I had in mind too. Problem is I will still have to enter that data manually(the parent linking column).

Comment: You should be able to generate the links using the `tnacecodes`. It shouldn't be too bad if you sort it beforehand.

Comment: It's still hundreds of data that needs to be entered.

Comment: You shouldn't have to enter it manually. Just use the number in the `tnacecodes` column to determine the parent.